# Nautilus interactive search activated only after typing second letter

Tags: nautilus, 17.04

I use Nautilus 3.22.1 in Ubuntu 17.04.

When I type a search word, the search text box appears without taking into account first letter of my word. So I have to type twice first letter, which is not practical.

Is there a parameter to change into preferences so the interactive search takes the whole search word without missing first letter ?
I looked up in Nautilus preferences with dconf but I did found any thing.